# Report with count from Mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a Mysql table with the following fields,

`bill_date,bill_no,item,tax,total.` 
i want to generate a report containing the fields

`bill_date,Bill_no,Taxable Item(Count),Nontaxable Item(Count)` between to dates. 
I try the query like this

`select Bill_no,bill_date,count(tax=0),count(tax>0) from bill group by bill_no`. The query return wrong values. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT bill_no, bill_date, 
    SUM(IF(tax=0, 1, 0)) AS nonTaxableItems,
    SUM(IF(tax>0, 1, 0)) AS taxableItems,
    FROM bill 
    WHERE bill_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
    GROUP BY bill_no
```

if you have the number of items stored in a column named count then the query becomes:

```
SELECT bill_no, bill_date, 
    SUM(IF(tax=0, count, 0)) AS nonTaxableItems,
    SUM(IF(tax>0, count, 0)) AS taxableItems,
    FROM bill 
    WHERE bill_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
    GROUP BY bill_no
```

Comment: Thanks friend, it's working. But I forgot to mention one more field. It's count. If someone buy an item more then one, the query will fail. Please update the query with count.

Also please clarify SUM(IF(tax=0, 1, 0)) it's new for me. Look like life saver for me.

Comment: IF(tax=0, 1, 0) will return 1 if tax=0, 0 otherwise. Then I sum all rows and I get the total of rows having tax=0. I don't understand what else you have to count, can you please make an example?

Comment: The query is ok if the customer buy an item more than one say(2), the query will fail. Please see the table structure.

bill_no  - int(11), item_name - varchar(50), tax_rate - decimal(10,2), tax   - decimal(10,2), price  - decimal(10,2), | count  - decimal(10,2), bill_date - datetime

Comment: Thanks friend, it's working. Also thanks for your explanation.